# Link to questions that I've answered in Stackoverflow Careers

Tags: feature-request

I would like to be able to link to all questions that I've answered in SO.

But I want to be able to select which tags to show questions for like this:

**Networking questions**

- Name of question 1
- Name of question 2

**ASP.NET MVC3 questions**

- Name of question 1
- Name of question 2

imho listing questions (and my answers) shows both my communication skills (hopefully clear and concise answers) and my actual programming skills.

Comment: Can't you do this already? Check the Top Answers section.

Comment: Well, yes. But that feature adds the questions directly and without organization. imho the CV gets a bit cluttered with it. I would like to add a list with links as in my example (organized by a header written by me).

Comment: I see. Perhaps you should ask for user defined headings.

Comment: It's not just the headings. I want **only** a link to the questions and not an abstract per question.